# Extending Sonarqube analyzers

Tags: sonarqube

I need to extend SonarQube, so that I can add new analyzers into it. I have tried adding a new rule for java files using xpath. I want to know how to add code analyzers in SonarQube for a new language, e.g. for `.meta` files.  How can I go about this?

Comment: You should provide more information on what you have done so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first entry point into the development of SonarQube analyzer is the [plugin development documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+Plugin). You might also want to have a look at the structure and architecture of existing language plugins, such as [JavaScript](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-javascript), [Groovy](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-groovy), [PHP](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-php) or [Java](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java).